# how can i change my http secure pages to https in cpanel

Tags: .htaccess, https, cpanel

how can i change my http sensitive pages to https while i don't now what is difference between http and https and how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is the secure version of HTTP:

- traffic gets encrypted,
- the user knows for sure that the site
  he is talking to is the real deal

Depending on your webserver, you'll have to add support for HTTPS in the configuration file. For example, for the [Apache Webserver](http://httpd.apache.org/), you need to edit use the [mod_ssl module](http://www.modssl.org/).